# How to populate the images on iphone screens in specific arrangements?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have few arrays of ccspirit images, these are balloons of different colors, like red, blue, green, etc

redArray having ccspirit of red colors,
greenArray having ccspirit of green colors,
blueArray having ccspirit of blue colors,
greenArray having ccspirit of green colors,

I want to populate them on screen as following

```
     0 0 0 0 0 0 
      0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0
```

can anyone give me, I also want their identification, so I think tag is best idea for it?

Help!

Comment: If you have a idea then implement that.. :)

Comment: I have idea, I can do start, but having some issue :-(

Comment: http://www.bubblegame.org/ see this link, and guide me a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tag to identify and place the sprites, that's the preferred way in Cocos2d.

Comment: I want like this, can you just give me starting point idea, if you have worked somewhere like this way

Comment: If you place all the colors in the same array, you should be able to pull them out one at a time in a for loop.  You could arrange them by having a horizontal (x) spacing value, say 30 points, then space the first row in this manner, alternating between colors.  Then on the next row, make the spacing twice as much (60). So in the loop, get the first sprite in the first array, set its position, then get the next sprite in the next array, set it's position + spacing value, and so on.  The next time through the loop, do the same thing but also add spacing to the vertical (y) position as well.

Comment: I got the idea, you want me to change the y axis by adding height of baloons, but javy, have you seen the shooting, if same color then it removes the baloons,else it be stay their, can you tell me what is logic behind this?

Comment: If you need them to stick next to each other, you will need to pre-calculate and store the positions that are possible in arrays, then use a lookup method to determine the closest position possible when a non-matching color collision happens, the  position the shot there.

Comment: I got the a bit idea, but I am upvoting you for helping me out, and giving me your precious time Sir :-)

Comment: you means x,y co-ordinates of ccspirits be predefined, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dummy parent CCNode, for instance located at center left of your screen, and have your balloons created as children using a displacement offset (increasing in a loop,  accounting and accumulating the respective width and height of each balloon).

The slight advantage here would be that you can easily have all your balloons move up or down at once (perhaps a scrolling motion, for instance) by simply moving the parent CCNode - but also that when trying to retrieve a balloon sprite by its tag, you can query using childByTag from your CCNode without risking tag value collisions with other sprites in your scene (say, UI buttons and other sprites unrelated to your gameplay).

Using tags to identify the balloons is a good idea, of course, but note that if you want to store and retrieve more custom data for your balloons (say - color, speed, etc ) you might want to consider subclassing CCSprite with your own sprite class, so that you can add any member variable you need.

I think there is also a way to attach userData to a CCNode, if subclassing is overkill for your needs.

Best,